# Can't Show full browser height

Tags: css, background-image

My code don't show browser full height with jQuery code
link -- https://goo.gl/RG60n1

here is my html --

```
      <div class="container contentContainer">

            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="topRow">

                <h1>Get Work. Done</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

here css --

```
  .contentContainer
        {
            background-image:url('laptop1.jpg');
            height:400px;
            width:100%;
            background-size:cover;
        }
```

And jquery --

```
    <script>

        $(".contentContainer").css("height",$(window).height());

   </script>
```

i am using jQuery 1.11.2 min version

Comment: Turn jQuery on lol! http://jsfiddle.net/ntmd7c31/

Comment: how to on jQuery... I m newbie... please help

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` or download it and set the src to the relative path.

Comment: ohhh I was did it... jQuery 1.11.2 min version

Comment: Yeah, it works with that version as well, check my fiddle :) don't forget to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Turn jQuery on! jsfiddle.net/ntmd7c31

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script‌​>`